# SLT Supported Target Databases / Change to non-HANA

Tags: hana, slt

When creating a configuration in transaction `LTRC` I see the option `Database System` as a drop-down-box.

HANA is preselected and the drop-down-box is grayed out. Is HANA the only option using a DB connection (which is needed for non-ABAP sources)?

[image: Specify Target System]

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the drop-down-box changeable (Enable targets other than HANA e.g. DB2) you need to have an appropriate license.

If you have the proper license then:

1. Use transaction `se16` to
2. modify table `DMC_RT_PARAMS`
3. change parameter with `PARAM_NAME = 'REPL_ENABLE_OTHER_TARGET'`
    
   to `PARAM_VALUE = 'X'`

**OR**

1. Use transaction `SE38`
2. Put `DMC_RT_PARAM_MAINT` in the input field and press execute / F8
3. Folder "Replikationsparameter" Parameter REPL_ENABLE_OTHER_TARGET Parameter Value: `X`